# MYSQL selection from tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have client which can have a project which project can have galleries which galleries have a images. So I create a tables: clients, projects, galleries, images in every table I have identifier in projects - client_id, galleries - project_id, images - gallery_id. I want to select all projects and galleries with all images for specific client. The problem is that I want to separate the galleries. That I can switch in the front end the galleries with buttons.

This is the full query but how to separate each gallery with the result:

```
SELECT im.image_name, im.gid, ga.gallery_name FROM images` AS im, `gallerys` AS ga ,     `projects` AS pr WHERE pr.id = ga.project_id AND ga.id = im.gid AND pr.id=$id
```

---

This is the solutions of the task:

```
SELECT group_concat( im.image_name ) , im.gid, ga.gallery_name
FROM `gl_images` AS im
JOIN `gl_gallerys` AS ga ON ga.id = im.gid
JOIN `gl_projects` AS pr ON pr.id = ga.project_id
WHERE pr.cid =43
GROUP BY ga.id
```

It is combined from the answers of  Joe Minichino and Gordon :)

Comment: Use the mySQL `GROUP BY` clause and group by ga.id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i think it's a HORRIBLE solution, you could try

```
SELECT group_concat(im.image_name) as image_names, 
group_concat(im.gid) as image_ids, 
ga.gallery_name 
FROM `images` AS im, `gallerys` AS ga, `projects` AS pr 
WHERE pr.id = ga.project_id AND ga.id = im.gid AND pr.id=$id
group by ga.id;
```

But if I were to do what you're doing I would at least process the result set at application level to obtain a tidier data structure i.e. instead of separate arrays of image names and ids, i'd try to create a json structure like

```
{ galleries : 
  [
   { galleryId: 1, images: [ { name: 'pic1.jpg', id: 1}, { name: 'pic2.jpg', id:2 }] },
  //   etc.
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks it will do the job just fine :}

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
SELECT im.image_name, im.gid, ga.gallery_name 
FROM `images` AS im, `gallerys` AS ga, `projects` AS pr 
WHERE pr.id = ga.project_id AND ga.id = im.gid AND pr.id=$id
 group by ga.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use proper `join` syntax instead of putting the join condition in the `where` clause.

Second, I don't exactly understand what you mean by:  "with all images for specific client."  But your query has `pr.id = $id` condition.  I think this should be `pr.client_Id = $id`.

Third, I'm not sure what you mean by "The problem is that i want to separate the galleries."  I think that sorting by `gallery_name` does what you want.

The final query is:

```
SELECT im.image_name, im.gid, ga.gallery_name
FROM `images` im join
      `gallerys` ga
      on ga.id = im.gid join
      `projects` pr 
      on pr.id = ga.project_id
where pr.client_Id = $id
order by ga.gallery_name;
```